# Must a vector subspace contain the null vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If it must, why? If it mustn't, why?
I was able to prove that a certain set of vectors doesn't have the zero vector as a member and normally, I've been told to conclude that it is not a vector subspace from this point. I got confused and wondered if this always shows that the set isn't an empty set since that is one of the conditions a vector subspace must satisfy.

Comment: Have you looked at the definition of a subspace lately? It must be a vector space in its own right, which necessitates a zero vector, which must coincide with the zero vector of the original space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U\subset V$ be a subspace. Since $U$ is non-empty there is a $u\in U$. Since $U$ is a subspace we get $-u\in U$. Hence also $0=u+(-u)\in U$.

Alternatively also $0=0_K\cdot u\in U$, where $0_K$ denotes the zero in the ground field $K$ (assuming $V$ is a $K$-vector space).

Comment: a simple and straight forward proof!